# Get the array with highest length from a parent array

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to get the array with the max length?

I have an array as follows,

```
main = [
         [1,2,3],
         [4],
         [5,6,7,8],
         [9,0]
       ]
```

I need to store the array with the max length, in this case

```
maxArray = main[2]
```

Comment: Is your main array always 2-level deep ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
main = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 0]
];

console.log(
  main.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
  })
);
```